# How to display Only spaces (...) without the ¶ in Netbeans "Show Non-printable Characters" mode?

Tags: netbeans, ide, whitespace

Is there any way how to hide the annoying ¶ character without hiding white-spaces?

To be specific, I want this:

```
....public static void main(String[] agrs){
........Map<Integer, List<Integer>> tableMap = new HashMap<>();
```

I don't want this:

```
¶
....public static void main(String[] agrs){¶
........Map<Integer, List<Integer>> tableMap = new HashMap<>();¶
```

the "show Non-printable characters" option displays both the dots for white spaces and the ¶ character at the end of line.. I just want the dots.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible. As whitespaces and lineends are displayed when you enable the option "show non-printable characters". The color of the whitespaces can be configured but the lineends are using the default color.

Comment: You can now follow the issue in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-1678

Answer (score 14):

I am using Netbeans 8.0.2, there is a plugin ("[Editor Whitespace](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/52662/editor-whitespace)") developed by "Tunnel Vision Labs" available to do somewhat like that.

Here is the plugin description:

> This module provides a generic whitespace highlighter for consistent
>   display when using the "Show Non-printable Characters" option in the
>   IDE. All tab and space characters are shown according to the
>   "Whitespace" color option, and newline characters are made invisible.

Comment: If you use Netbeans 8.1 and you cannot find this plugin in the list of available plugins, you can always manually download and install this plugin in Netbeans by file, after which it works just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a reasonable RFE. +1  So please file an issue at https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/

Since 7.4 you can change the color of trailing whitespaces. May be this will help you.

http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB74#Indentation_and_Trailing_Whitespace_Highlighting_added

Answer (score 2):

In Netbeans IDE 8.0.2 you manipulate the EOL character's colour this way:

1. Make sure that **View >> Show Non-printable Characters** is selected.
2. Go to **Tools >> Options >> Fonts & Colors >> Syntax tab** and adjust **Default** colour's foreground to match the background (or set it different enough to be visible but not distracting):

[image]

3. [ Optional ] Modify the **Whitespace** colour in the same menu, independently.
4. [ Optional ] In **Highlighting tab** change the **Trailing Whitespace**'s colour if you want it to be different than the **Whitespace**.

So far I haven't noticed any 'disappearing' code.

Comment: In NetBeans 8.1 the Default color seems to also affect the color of the braces.

Comment: The trick is to not only change the color for category Default as explained above, but to also change every other category to define their own color *instead* of inheriting from Default. This is how I got it done in NB 8.1.

Comment: After some time trying this solution, I have to say it's not really doable, since *a lot* of categories depend on the foreground color set in the Default category. If I still need to see those, I have to change a million other categories to set the color from `inherited` to something useful. I've used the Editor Whitespace plugin from another answer instead.